# DateTime.TryParseExact doesnt work - returns false but should be true

Tags: c#, .net

I try to validate a DateTime object with TryParseExact. The mission is to check if the DateTime contains Time and not just Date. The code that I have so far:

```
public bool validateDateAndTime(DateTime checkDateFormat)
{
      checkDateFormat = new DateTime(2019, 02, 02, 23, 33, 21); 
      DateTime checkOutDate; 
      if(DateTime.TryParseExact(checkDateFormat.ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out checkOutDate))
      {
          return true;
      }
      else
      {
          Console.WriteLine(checkDateFormat.ToString() + " " + checkOutDate);
          return false;
      }
}
```

This makes no sense to me since I set `"yyyy, mm, dd, hh, mm, ss"`, just before the if case.

The printed console line:

> 2019-02-02 23:33:21 0001-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: Is `hh` 12 hour time, or 24 hour? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#hhSpecifier

Comment: Why are you trying to validate a date that you already know is valid? Also, this code is not safe. If you are going to do `ToString` on a date, you should be specific about the format as the output of that will change depending on the culture of the host system.

Comment: `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` since `hh` is **12** hour format

Comment: If you just want to check if the datetime has hour/minute/second -value set, simply compare those: if (date.Hour > 0)...

Answer (score -1):

Your ToString() output doesn't match to exact format of yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:

```
public bool validateDateAndTime(DateTime checkDateFormat)
{
    checkDateFormat = new DateTime(2019, 02, 02, 23, 33, 21);
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(checkDateFormat.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out DateTime checkOutDate))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Validated: {checkOutDate}");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(checkDateFormat.ToString() + " " + checkOutDate);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining downvote. It was exactly the reason.

Answer (score -1):

You are actually converting DateTime.ToString(), which by default is General format and is under en-US culture.

If you want to display the time in a different format then specify it's format.

Try this,

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(checkDateFormat.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", 
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out odate);
```